# Cloud file storage with file tagging and search by tags/filename

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-datastore, tagging, azure-cognitive-search

My project needs to meet next requirements.

- store large amount of files for reasonable price
- tag individual files with custom tags
- have API method to search files by name (contains) and tags (exact)
- do it all via JS SDK (keep project serverless)

I made some work with Amazon S3 and turned out

- no search method in JS SDK http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#listObjectsV2-property
- `listObjects` accepts param Key Prefix (i.e. filename `starts with`), so there is no way to find by `contains`
- no param to search by tag at all, i can only get it for individual file with `getObjectTagging`

So question is - what stable service can i use for file storage WITH functionality described above

Azure?  Google Cloud? Backblaze B2? something else?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Azure blob storage, you can use [Azure Search blob indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage) to index both the metadata and textual content of your blobs. For a walkthrough of setting this up, see [Build and query your first Azure Search index in the portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/search-get-started-portal).

Comment: thanks. in the meantime i found https://www.storagemadeeasy.com/

It is aggregator   40+ cloud service providers with tagging ability and S3 compatible API